# What if husband wants to watch pornography videos while sex but wife knows it's haram and deny to watch it? Am i obliged to obey him in wrong doings?

Tags: sex, pornography

My husbnd wants us to watch pornography videos during sex. I personally dont like it. It feels me that he has more interest in those videos than me . What should i do now? Am i obliged to obey him in this matter? To protect my marriage? Please enlighten me on this issue in the light of islam.
Thank you

Comment: Watching pornography is haram. You can not obey your husband in anything that involves sin as the [hadith](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/95/12) says:  لا طاعة في معصية، إنما الطاعة في المعروف There is No obedience for evil deeds, obedience is required only in what is good.